# Keyboard short-cut for New file for Sidebar Enhancement plugin in Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

I want that if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> I should have same functionality as when I right on my side bar and do new file i.e. I should be asked to put in a file name.

I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> will focus me on the sidebar. But still takes too many steps.

Or any other method since I only want to put in a file name with extension when new file is opened otherwise it won't syntax highlight my code.

Comment: I would recommend checking out the [AdvancedNewFile](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile) plugin for Sublime.

Comment: @saadq awesome, so much of code for just a simple functionality, kudos to writers.

Comment: @saadq do u know of something to get console input for python. It's the most buggy thing for me right now. All answers I see are for `SublimeREPL` and in that you have to go manually to tool>SublimeREPL>python>run current file.  Or maybe similarly key binding can be created for this thing.

Comment: @saadq But I am facing one problem it's making up the new file in root folder instead of the one in which I am currently working.

Answer (score 1):

[AdvancedNewFile](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile)   worked perfect for my purpose. Just a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> voila you are done.

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Open:
Preferences -> Package Settings -> Side Bar -> Key Bindings - User

Paste this:

```
[
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+alt+n"],
        "command": "side_bar_new_file"
    },
]
```

Bonus shortcut:

```
{
    "keys": ["f2"],
    "command": "side_bar_rename"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on: **Sublime Text Build 4113**

For package [FileManager](https://github.com/math2001/FileManager).

Open: *Preferences -> Key Bindings - User*

Paste this code:

```
[
    {
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+n"],
    "command": "fm_create",
    "args": { "initial_text": "$here/" }
    },
]
```

> Note: `"args": { "initial_text": "$here/" }` allows you to create the
> new file on the same route as the current file (thaks [OdatNurd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953535/how-to-create-a-directory-faster-in-sublime-text-3)).
> Look at the `"aliases"` section in *Preferences -> Package Settings -> FileManager* to see other Alias useful in addition to `"$here/"`

Then, press the assigned keys, this will open an input.

Write part of the name of an existing folder, and just press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle through the auto completion.

If you want to create nested folders, write the names of the intermediate folders and pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, these will be created.

If the last character you type in is a `/` folder will be created. Otherwise it will be a file.

Comment: FileManager has a default keyboard shortcut `"alt+n"`, but this is in conflict with alt-underline keyboard shortcut to _Preferences_ in _menu bar_ of Sublime Text.
To disable this shortcut `"alt+n"` in FileManager, go to _Preferences -> Package Settings -> FileManager_ and see the bottom of the default setting file (left) and copy `"create_keybinding_enabled"` to user setting file (right) and set it in false.