# How to create a directory faster in Sublime Text 3

Tags: file, sublimetext3, workflow

Whenever I create a directory in Sublime Text 3 I just either:

1. Open the directory tree in the sidebar, create the directory one folder at a time...
2. Or do the same thing in the Finder window.
3. Or (rarely) open up the terminal and do `mkdir -p <path>`.

Wondering if there is a plugin or a way or something to just do:

<kbd>⌘p</kbd> `my/long/directory/name` <kbd>enter</kbd>

Or the same thing for files

<kbd>⌘p</kbd> `my/long/file/name.txt` <kbd>enter</kbd>

And it creates it super fast if it doesn't exist. That would streamline the workflow quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FileManager](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileManager) plugin sounds like it might be of use to you. Among the features it provides, it's `fm_create` command allows you to create files or folders, including automatically creating any path elements that don't exist.

The command is bound to <kbd>Alt+N</kbd> by default (across all platforms) and is also available in the command palette as `File Manager: New File`. Despite the name of the command, it creates both files and folders and uses the last character to determine which you meant to create:

> FileManager doesn't have a command create_new_file and create_new_folder. Just fm_create. It opens up an input, and the last character you type in is a / (or a ), it creates a folder instead of a file.

In addition the input supports auto-completion of paths and it's fairly customizable as well. For example, I added this command to a `Defaults.sublime-commands` in my `User` package to implement a command that allows me to easily create a file at the same path as the current file:

```json
{
    "caption": "File Manager: New File Relative to Current View",
    "command": "fm_create",
    "args": { "initial_text": "$here/" }
},
```